# prove $(\hat{f}g)^\lor$=$f*g^{\lor}$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I want to prove that $(\hat{f}g)^\lor$=$f*g^{\lor}$ give that $f$,$g$:$\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{C}$ are integratble functions.

I know that $\hat{f}$ is bounded an the function $g$ is integratble zo the product $\hat{f}.g$ is integratble. This means that the left side of the equation makes sense. Now the function $f$ is intgratble and $\check{g}$ is bounded. This means that $f*\check{g}$ is well defined.

So I tried to fill in the left side of the formula and then with the Fubini positive , I tried to rewrite it to the right side of the formula but it never works out. I think I don't get how you need to fill in with several variables. Is there someone who can prove it?

Comment: Your notation seems non-standard. I take it $\hat{f}$ is the Fourier transform of $f$ (which is perfectly standard). Is $h^{\wedge}$ supposed to be the inverse Fourier transform?

Comment: I'm sorry where do you see an h?

Comment: @WoolierThanThou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align}
(\hat f g)^{\vee} (x)&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\hat f(t) g(t) e^{2\pi ity}dy \\
     &= \int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(y)  e^{-2\pi ity} g(t) e^{2\pi ity} dtdy
\\    &=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(y)\int_{\mathbb{R}}   g(t) e^{2\pi it(x-y)} dtdy
\\&=\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(y)\check g(x-y)dy
\\&=(\hat fg)^{\vee}(x)
\end{align}